# Understanding "come back to you on something"

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

I am learning English, but I am not familiar with idioms. Could somebody explain me in plain English what does it mean "I will need to come back to you on this request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually hear this as "I will have to get back to you on this" in AmE, although "come back to you" is also used. It means, I will have to do some investigation or work before I can fulfill your request or answer your question. For example,

> "Can you tell me the date of my last payment?"
>   "Let me check my files and come back to you on that. Is there anything else I can help you with?"

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, "get back to you" is more common than "come back to you", but the context suggests it's the same meaning.

It means "I cannot answer you right now, but I will answer you later."

- Maybe the speaker doesn't know the answer yet, and so plans to go research it, and then tell you the answer based on their research.
- Maybe the speaker does know the answer, but doesn't have time to deliver the answer properly right now.  (Because the answer is long and complex, or requires a diagram, or something.)
- Maybe the speaker doesn't know if they have permission to answer you - the information may be confidential, so they need to go find out if they're allowed to disclose it to you.